# Image in layout is not completely on top, where I want it

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

[Edit, it's on top, now it's zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRis.png)

If it's possible, i would want it to fill the entire screen, width wise, with the image, completely on top, leaving no space between the top and the image. This is not working for me.

This is the main.xml code that I have, it could be completely wrong, please tell me if that's the case.

[This is how it looks in the emulator, I want it to fill the entire top side from left to right, completely on the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3MCc.png)

Any help would be appreciated, i'm pretty new to this, so don't be scared to tell me i'm wrong :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
         />

  </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Nieuws" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Contact" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="  Geef je mening!" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=" Route begeleiding" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Specia-listen" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BWC" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Agenda" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Praktische
 informatie" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_alignParentTop="true" on ImageView and remove all android:padding*******="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
   android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
  />
```

Comment: This makes it will the entire screen from left to right, but zooms in my image completely.

Comment: wiil you please share the screen shot. so that i can check it how it looks?

Comment: added to the post, on top is the link to the image

Comment: add this android:scaleType="fitXY"  instead of   android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Okay so that did it. Image is pulled out, obviously, which makes the letters look really bad. That's not code wise but just image wise. Your code is flawless, thanks! :) Not sure how i'm gonna do this, but i think i just need to create an own image and keep in mind that i will width out. Will be hard, but i'm gonna try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just remove your paddings. I hope it will help

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: I completely removed those 4 lines, nothing changed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: sorry you have to remove also your gravity android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

Remove two line in layout root

```
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Nieuws" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Afspraak   maken" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Bezoek  tijden" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Contact" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="  Geef je mening!" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=" Route begeleiding" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Specia-listen" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BWC" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Agenda" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Praktische informatie" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! This made the space on top go away, and now the image is on top. Now it just needs to fill the entire width. Not sure if that's possible without ruining the image, as it might just not be the right image for that.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` on the parent of the `ImageView` is ignored because its parent (the root view) is not a `RelativeLayout`. Try changing the root view to `RelativeLayout`, and remove its padding (at least the top one).